# dynamic creation of roles with spring specurity

Tags: java, spring-security, acl

I'm working on a content-management type web app that uses spring security (version 3.0.5) for authentication and standard RBAC to coarsely define groups of users.

One of the features of the application will be to enable users with certain roles (e.g., admin) to configure the permissions on individual users ( or groups of individual users) to access  specific items of content, and also control the operations they can perform on that content (e.g., read/write/delete, but also export, print, share, grant permissions etc). Also these admin users will be define roles that encapsulate commonly used permission sets.  So it seems I'll need Access Control Lists.

But reading the Spring ACL documentation, it's a bit unclear to me if this sort of dynamic definition of roles/users at runtime by end-users is supported; it seems to me that the main 'out of the box' use case of Spring ACL uses static definitions declared in the application itself.

I'd like to use Spring ACL  if possible - the benefits that appear most attractive are a) Performant bit-masked operations, b) Keeping the permissions lookups in wrapping proxies outside of our business code, c) Standard technology; BUT if to accommodate our use case requires reimplementing  most  the Spring security interfaces then we might just roll our own.

So I'd like to  ask if anyone has successfully used Spring ACL in this sort of use case? Is it recommended or discouraged  to  programmatically modify the Spring ACL tables dynamically at runtime  as roles and permissions are altered by users?

Thanks

Richard

Answer (score 0):

use this :-

```
<intercept-url pattern="/admin*" **access="hasRole('SYS_ADMIN')"** />
```

Comment: yes, that will enable a general role but not the resource-specific, fine grained access. There's a tutorial I came across [here](http://blog.denksoft.com/?page_id=20) that explains nicely how to update ACL tables, which answers my second question